# How to simulate a SIM card for android

Tags: android, android-emulator, simulator, sim-card

I do not have a real android device. I completely depend on emulator. So, for the sim contacts, changing sim cards and other purposes regarding sim, i want a simulator for SIM. I didn't find any thing regarding this in our default emulator. Can anyone please help me with any idea on this and any links to third party SIM simulators for android emulator. Thank you in advance..

Comment: If your time has even the slightest value, I think it would probably be cheaper to buy an (older?) android device on the used market.  As some point you really need to test your app on hardware anyway, to get a true measure of usability.

Comment: I have only 1 of 3 usb ports working on my laptop its getting really loose so I need this answer tool

Comment: @Chris Stratton Yes, but computer (our) knowledge doesn't progress like this.

Answer (score 8):

May this help you:

Buddy in Document it is said that Emulators are supported with simulated SimCard..
**"A GSM modem, including a simulated SIM Card"** [More Information](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

And There are some patches available which allows sim card support in emulator using standard USB PCSC reader...

Here are some links which may guide you through..

- http://simhacks.github.io/android-emulator/
- http://blog.codepainters.com/2010/11/20/android-emulator-patch-for-configurable-imei-imsi-and-sim-card-serial-number/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in which I needed to obtain contacts from my SIM to test with my application. Furthermore to my understanding the only solution I resulted in was buying an android mobile and performed tests using that as I could not find such a SIM emulator.